# How to unpivot in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, transpose, unpivot

Not sure what functions to call, but transpose is the closest thing I can think of.

I have a table in BigQuery that is configured like this:
[image]

but I want to query a table that is configured like this:

[image]

What does the SQL code look like for creating this table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**2020 update**: `fhoffa.x.unpivot()`

See:

- https://medium.com/@hoffa/how-to-unpivot-multiple-columns-into-tidy-pairs-with-sql-and-bigquery-d9d0e74ce675

I created a public persistent UDF. If you have a table `a`, you can give the whole row to the UDF for it to be unpivotted:

```
SELECT geo_type, region, transportation_type, unpivotted
FROM `fh-bigquery.public_dump.applemobilitytrends_20200414` a
  , UNNEST(fhoffa.x.unpivot(a, '_2020')) unpivotted
```

It transforms a table like this:

[image]

Into this

[image]

---

As a comment mentions, my solution above doesn't solve for the question problem.

So here's a variation, while I look how to integrate all into one:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION unpivot(x ANY TYPE) AS (
(
  SELECT 
   ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
     REGEXP_EXTRACT(y, '[^"]+') AS key
   , REGEXP_EXTRACT(y, ':([0-9]+)') AS value
   ))
  FROM UNNEST((
    SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(json,'"[smlx][meaxl]'||r'[^:]+:\"?[^"]+?') arr
    FROM (SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(x) json))) y
)
);

SELECT location, unpivotted.*
FROM `robotic-charmer-726.bl_test_data.reconfiguring_a_table` x
  , UNNEST(unpivot(x)) unpivotted
```

---

*Previous answer:*

Use the UNION of tables (with ',' in BigQuery), plus some column aliasing:

```
SELECT Location, Size, Quantity
FROM (
  SELECT Location, 'Small' as Size, Small as Quantity FROM [table]
), (
  SELECT Location, 'Medium' as Size, Medium as Quantity FROM [table]
), (
  SELECT Location, 'Large' as Size, Large as Quantity FROM [table]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful response @FelipeHoffa !!
It didn't need the second and third 'FROM'. So in the end it worked like this:
'SELECT Location, Size, Quantity
FROM (
  SELECT Location, 'Small' as Size, Small as Quantity FROM [table]
),
(
  SELECT Location, 'Medium' as Size, Medium as Quantity FROM [table]
),
 (
  SELECT Location, 'Large' as Size, Large as Quantity FROM [table]
)'

Thanks!

Comment: right! query fixed (if you upload sample data to BQ, then I can test my queries before pasting them here)

Comment: Good to know! How do I point you to my BigQuery dataset? (I am currently only querying things using Tableau and the BigQuery Web UI, so I have no idea how to give someone directions to my datasets.
Thanks

Comment: If you make a dataset public, then anyone on StackOverflow can look at it and give a hand :). For example, this is my wikipedia pageviews log for August: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_201408  (project:dataset.table)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think I did this right... [link](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/robotic-charmer-726:bl_test_data.reconfiguring_a_table)
I shared the table with 'All Authenticated Users' and made the cloud storage file public.
Thanks

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I tried to apply the UDF to OP's case, to test with list of definites columns but it also unpivots `location`: `SELECT location, unpivotted
FROM robotic-charmer-726.bl_test_data.reconfiguring_a_table a
  , UNNEST(fhoffa.x.unpivot(a, '[small|medium|large|xl|xxl]')) unpivotted`

Comment: Thanks for this 2020 update congrartulations. Just to warn that this works, as far as the columns are not nested inside an struct themselves. where they key values start to do wired things. still the implementation of it had been a great source of inspiration. Thanks again.

Comment: The regular expressions did not work for my data, which has strings in the `value` which contain special characters.  These regular expressions work for my data.

`CREATE TEMP FUNCTION unpivot(x ANY TYPE) AS (
(
  SELECT 
   ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
     REGEXP_EXTRACT(y, r'"([^"]+)"') AS key
   , coalesce(REGEXP_EXTRACT(y, r':\"(.+)\"'), REGEXP_EXTRACT(y, r':([^",]+)')) AS value
   ))
  FROM UNNEST((
    SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(json,r'"[^"]+":\"[^"]+\"|"[^"]+":[^,]+') arr
    FROM (SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(x) json))) y
)
);`

Comment: This is A-M-A-Z-I-N-G !! Very intelligent technique.

Answer (score 34):

**Update 2021:**

A new [UNPIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unpivot_operator) operator has been introduced into BigQuery.

Before UNPIVOT is used to rotate Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 into sales and quarter columns:

| product | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kale | 51 | 23 | 45 | 3 |
| Apple | 77 | 0 | 25 | 2 |

After UNPIVOT is used to rotate Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 into sales and quarter columns:

| product | sales | quarter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kale | 51 | Q1 |
| Kale | 23 | Q2 |
| Kale | 45 | Q3 |
| Kale | 3 | Q4 |
| Apple | 77 | Q1 |
| Apple | 0 | Q2 |
| Apple | 25 | Q3 |
| Apple | 2 | Q4 |

Query:

```
WITH Produce AS (
  SELECT 'Kale' as product, 51 as Q1, 23 as Q2, 45 as Q3, 3 as Q4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 77, 0, 25, 2
)
SELECT * FROM Produce
UNPIVOT(sales FOR quarter IN (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4))
```

Comment: Why was this voted down? I could solve my problem like this.

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer

Comment: How to add all columns except one into `in()` statement dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

@Felipe, I tried this using standard-sql but I get an error on the first line of your query that says: "Column name Location is ambiguous at [1:8]"

I've used an alternate query that works for me:

```
SELECT Location, 'Small' as Size, Small as Quantity FROM `table`
UNION ALL
SELECT Location, 'Medium' as Size, Medium as Quantity FROM `table`
UNION ALL
SELECT Location, 'Large' as Size, Large as Quantity FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that uses `STRUCT`s, `ARRAY`s and `CROSS JOIN` + `UNNEST`:

```
WITH
  My_Table_Metrics_Data AS (
  SELECT
    ...,
    [
        STRUCT('...' AS Metric, ... AS Data),
        STRUCT('...' AS Metric, ... AS Data),
    ] AS Metrics_Data
  FROM
    `My_Dataset.My_Table`
  WHERE
    ...
  )
SELECT
  ...,
  Metric_Data
FROM
  My_Table_Metrics_Data
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(My_Table_Metrics_Data.Metrics_Data) AS Metric_Data
```

Full explanation and instructions: https://yuhuisdatascienceblog.blogspot.com/2018/06/how-to-unpivot-table-in-bigquery.html