# SQL Transpose and Add Column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following structure (header):

```
ProjID,Cost2001,Cost2002,Cost2003
```

So for example the first two rows look like so:

```
projectA,10,32,30
projectB,42,22,122
```

I would like to transform this table into the following structure (header):

```
ProjID,CostYear,Value
```

So that coming back to the sample data, post the transformation, it would look like so:

```
ProjectA,Cost2001,10
ProjectA,Cost2002,32
ProjectA,Cost2003,30
ProjectB,Cost2001,42
ProjectB,Cost2002,22
ProjectB,Cost2003,122
```

How do I do this? I'm using Google BigQuery, which supports [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/). I only need to do this one time to fix the table, so I don't mind importing the data to another RDBMS in order to be able to use pivot functionality.

Comment: please tag right RDBMS, `Mysql or T-sql` ?

Comment: This functionality is commonly called `UNPIVOT`. How to do this depends on your database (actual `UNPIVOT` function or a `UNION`).

Comment: Ideally once you get your data in this format you fix your tables so they are permanently like this. What you have violates 1NF with what is known as repeating groups. It should be rows instead. Ideally you would have a column named CostYear which would only have the year value. As already said you need to decided which DBMS you are using. But regardless you need an UNPIVOT

Comment: @BHouse I added the info about the RDMBS. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you [unpivot google big query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832170/how-to-unpivot-in-bigquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO the easiest way is using UNION ALL.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE projects(ProjID VARCHAR(20), Cost2001 int, Cost2002 int, Cost2003 int);
> INSERT INTO projects VALUES
> ('projectA', 10, 32, 30),
> ('projectB', 42, 22, 122);
>
> CREATE TABLE new_projects (ProjID VARCHAR(20), ProjYear INT, Cost int);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO new_projects
> SELECT ProjID, 2001, Cost2001
> FROM   projects
> UNION ALL
> SELECT ProjID, 2002, Cost2002
> FROM   projects
> UNION ALL
> SELECT ProjID, 2003, Cost2003
> FROM   projects;
>
> SELECT * FROM new_projects;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ProjID   | ProjYear | Cost
> :------- | -------: | ---:
> projectA |     2001 |   10
> projectB |     2001 |   42
> projectA |     2002 |   32
> projectB |     2002 |   22
> projectA |     2003 |   30
> projectB |     2003 |  122
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7ab0b3f12ab4c17dd5cafdfceaaec688)*

Answer (score 3):

Below are truly BigQuery style :o)

Both versions for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
##standardSQL
SELECT 
  projID,  
  ([2001, 2002, 2003])[SAFE_OFFSET(pos)] year, 
  cost
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([Cost2001,Cost2002,Cost2003]) cost WITH OFFSET pos
```

you can test / play wit above using dummy data from your question as below

```sql
##standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'projectA' projID, 10 Cost2001, 32 Cost2002, 30 Cost2003 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'projectB', 42, 22, 122 
)
SELECT 
  projID,  
  ([2001, 2002, 2003])[SAFE_OFFSET(pos)] year, 
  cost
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([Cost2001,Cost2002,Cost2003]) cost WITH OFFSET pos
```

with result as

```sql
Row projID      year    cost     
1   projectA    2001    10   
2   projectA    2002    32   
3   projectA    2003    30   
4   projectB    2001    42   
5   projectB    2002    22   
6   projectB    2003    122
```

as you can see in above query you had to pre-set values for respective years in below line

```sql
([2001, 2002, 2003])[SAFE_OFFSET(pos)] year
```

If for whatever reason you want to be more generic and be able to derive those values off of original columns' names - you can use below generic approach

```sql
##standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'projectA' projID, 10 Cost2001, 32 Cost2002, 30 Cost2003 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'projectB', 42, 22, 122 
)
SELECT 
  projID,  
  SPLIT(x,':')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] year,
  SPLIT(x,':')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] cost 
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'[{}"]', ''))) x
WHERE SPLIT(x,':')[OFFSET(0)] != 'projID'
```

obviously, with same result

```sql
Row projID      year        cost     
1   projectA    Cost2001    10   
2   projectA    Cost2002    32   
3   projectA    Cost2003    30   
4   projectB    Cost2001    42   
5   projectB    Cost2002    22   
6   projectB    Cost2003    122
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone mentioned, you need `UNPIVOT` for this, which would look something like:

```
DECLARE @projects TABLE (projid nvarchar(max), cost2001 int, cost2002 int, cost2003 int);

INSERT @projects VALUES ('projectA', 10, 32, 30)
                    , ('projectB', 42, 22, 122);


SELECT PROJID, PROJECT_ATTRIBUTE, PROJECT_COST
FROM @projects
UNPIVOT (PROJECT_COST FOR PROJECT_ATTRIBUTE in (cost2001, cost2002, cost2003) ) AS UNPVT
```

I wouldn't go for using the `UNION ALL` version for performance reasons. Essentially you would be scanning the table 3 times or as many "CostYear" columns you have, plus you have to add a whole new query for that.

As opposed to scanning the table once with a `UNPIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot your data

```
DECLARE @ProjectTbl TABLE (ProjectID VARCHAR(225),Cost2001 INT, Cost2002 INT,Cost2003  INT)
INSERT INTO @ProjectTbl VALUES
('projectA',10,32,30),
('projectB',42,22,122);

;WITH Unpivots 
AS
(SELECT 
*
FROM @ProjectTbl
UNPIVOT 
(
  Value FOR CostYear IN (Cost2001, Cost2002, Cost2003)
) AS up 
)
SELECT
ProjectID,
CostYear,
Value
FROM Unpivots
```

OutPut

```
ProjectID   CostYear    Value
projectA    Cost2001    10
projectA    Cost2002    32
projectA    Cost2003    30
projectB    Cost2001    42
projectB    Cost2002    22
projectB    Cost2003    122
```