# Transposing output in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have following data

```
Column0      Column1     Column2     Column3    Column4
node10        node11      node12      node13
node20        node21      node22      node23     node24
node30        node31      node32                 
node40        node41      node42      node43     node44
```

Some of the rows may have data until Column3 (like Row1) and some other may end at Column4 (like Row2)
The Column0 is always present and is root for respective rows

I would need to have the output this way

```
Column0     temporaryColumns   finalColumns    rank
node10       node11               node13        1
node10       node12               node13        2
node20       node21               node24        1
node20       node22               node24        2
node20       node23               node24        3
node30       node31               node31        1
node40       node41               node44        1
node40       node42               node44        2
node40       node43               node44        3
```

Comment: check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832170/how-to-unpivot-in-bigquery

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  Column0, 
  arr[ORDINAL(i)] AS temporaryColumns, 
  arr[ORDINAL(len)] AS finalColumns,
  i - 1 AS `rank`
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST([REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMAT('%t', t), r'\(|\)|, NULL', '')]) list,
UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(list) AS arr)]),
UNNEST([ARRAY_LENGTH(arr)]) len,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(2, len - 1)) i
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'node10' Column0, 'node11' Column1, 'node12' Column2, 'node13' Column3, NULL Column4 UNION ALL    
  SELECT 'node20', 'node21', 'node22', 'node23', 'node24' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'node30', 'node31', 'node32', NULL, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'node40', 'node41', 'node42', 'node43', 'node44' 
)
SELECT 
  Column0, 
  arr[ORDINAL(i)] AS temporaryColumns, 
  arr[ORDINAL(len)] AS finalColumns,
  i - 1 AS `rank`
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST([REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMAT('%t', t), r'\(|\)|, NULL', '')]) list,
UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(list) AS arr)]),
UNNEST([ARRAY_LENGTH(arr)]) len,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(2, len - 1)) i
```

output is as below

```
Row Column0 temporaryColumns    finalColumns    rank     
1   node10  node11              node13          1    
2   node10  node12              node13          2    
3   node20  node21              node24          1    
4   node20  node22              node24          2    
5   node20  node23              node24          3    
6   node30  node31              node32          1    
7   node40  node41              node44          1    
8   node40  node42              node44          2    
9   node40  node43              node44          3
```

Comment: have you tried? Have it worked for you? consider voting up if it helped. and accept